# how to override module's theme function in a custom module?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm a Drupal8 newbie. I installed a third party module [simplelogin](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplelogin), and I attempted to change the `{{site_name}}` value in `page--simplelogin.html.twig` but can not find a right way.

I noticed that the variable is defined in simplelogin.module:

```
function simplelogin_preprocess_simplelogin(&$variables) {
  $path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'simplelogin');

  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'simplelogin/simplelogin-library';

  // Able to use custom variables
  $variables['path'] = $path;
  $variables['base_path'] = base_path();
  $variables['logo'] = file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url(theme_get_setting('logo.url')));
  $variables['background_class'] = simple_login_settings('active');
  $variables['background_opacity'] = simple_login_settings('opacity');
  $variables['wrapper_width'] = simple_login_settings('width');
  $variables['site_name'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');
  $variables['site_register'] = \Drupal::config('user.settings')->get('register');
}
```

I guess the second "simplelogin" presented in the hook function is a form element in the theme (I'm not quite clear although), as I found `$form['simplelogin']` appears in the buildForm function of form controller.

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, Request $request = NULL) {

    $form_state->disableCache();

    $simplelogin_config = $this->config('simplelogin.settings');

    $imageid = $simplelogin_config->get('background_image');
    if ($imageid) {
      $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($imageid[0]);  // File Load 
      $fileUrl = $file->getFileUri();

      // check if image is valid.
      $image = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($fileUrl);
      if ($image->isValid()) {
        $image_render = array(
          '#theme' => 'image_style',
          '#width' => $image->getWidth(),
          '#height' => $image->getHeight(),
          '#style_name' => 'medium',
          '#uri' => $fileUrl,
        );
      }
    }
    //$renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
    //$renderer->addCacheableDependency($image_render, $file);

    $form['simplelogin'] = array(
      '#type'            => 'details',
      '#title'           => $this->t('Configuration'),
      '#open'            => TRUE,

      'background_active' => array(
```

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:**
                                                                                                  1. created a custom module named "mylogin", this is the info.yml:

```
name: myLogin
description: my login module
type: module

version: '8.x-1.0'
package: 8.x
core: '8.x'
project: 'mylogin'

dependencies:
  - simplelogin
```

2. override hook_preprocess_page in mylogin.module:

```
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\simplelogin\Controller;

function mylogin_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'user.login') {
    $variables['site_name']= 'test';
  }
}
```

But it cannot work, and I believe the preprocess is not triggered. Is there a simple way to override the needed variable while keep the others in the module's preprocess function? Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new module use hook_theme_registry_alter like module [simplelogin](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/simplelogin/tree/simplelogin.module#n176)
like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['page__simplelogin'][preprocess functions] = [
    0 => 'simplelogin_preprocess_simplelogin',
    1 => 'YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_function'
  ];
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still not triggered the preprocess function...

Comment: Did you try clear cache? If doesn' working try create module start with string t (u, v .. string after S).

Comment: Yes, I did clear cache. What do you mean by "create module start with string...", rename the module?

Comment: Yes, the list hooks is array.  I guess this array order by module name. So may be your hook run before simplelogin's hook.

Comment: Do I need to declare the function path somewhere? The two functions locate in different place.

Comment: I think, you don't need. Because your hook  just alter **preprocess functions**.

Comment: Oh yes! You're right. After I create a new module named xylogin, it triggers the preprocess function. This seems weird, what if I have no name to use after the predefined fucntion? Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: You can try research with key word "module weight".

Comment: :D and don't missing accept my answer.